# Is it safe to return while EOFException occurred

Tags: java, inputstream

When I copy `Inputstream` to `OutputStream` , sometimes I occur the `EOFException`.

From the document of `EOFException` may used by data input streams to signal end of stream.

So does it mean that it's safe to return when a `EOFException` occurred ?

```
public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

byte[] buff = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
int n = -1;

try {
  while ((n = in.read(buff)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buff, 0, n);
  }
} catch (EOFException eof) {
  // reach EOF , return
}
```

}

Comment: by the way this code is used when I fetch html from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOFException cannot be thrown in InputStream.read(byte[]), its API says IOException is thrown "if the first byte cannot be read for any reason other than the end of the file...".

EOFException  is used for other purposes, eg. java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(byte[] b) may throw EOFException if input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.

But, in any case, EOFException indicates that an error occurred, you should not ignore it and return as if nothing happened.

Comment: in my case this happens when read things from `InflaterInputStream`

Comment: 1) InflaterInputStream API does not say that 2) See InflaterInputStream source EOFException is never thrown in the code, only ZIPException and IOException.

Comment: Sorry, it's  `GZIPInputStream` actually

Comment: It's not declared in its API either. But, in any case, it is abnormal situation. It is not normal EOF "// reach EOF , return"  do not catch it

Comment: YES that's unnormal ,  the server side sends more bytes than excepted so this exception happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you read correctly from the `InputStream`, this exception will not get thrown. Reaching the end of the file is expected when there is no more data. The last call to `read` will return `-1` and all later calls to `read` will throw the exception. It is safe to return the value when you catch the exception but you should avoid the error altogether. Something like this should do:

```
public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

  byte[] buff = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
  int n = -1;

  try {
    while ((n = in.read(buff)) != -1) { //See the JavaDoc
      out.write(buff, 0, n);
  }
  catch (IOException eof) {
     e.printStackTrace(); //So you know if something happens...
  }
}
```

By the way, the `read` method throws an `IOException`, not an `EOFException`...

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream.read(byte[])` will just try to fill as many bytes as it can read into the `byte[]`, and it will return `-1` if it reached EOF. So `EOFException` wouldn't be thrown normally. `EOFException` is thrown for unexpected circumstances. So you should ideally just throw this exception rather than catching it, because it means there is something wrong in the logic itself.

You should use `InputStream.read(byte[]) == -1` to check for EOF. Using the exception to determine if the end of stream is reached is a bad idea, because exceptions are expensive.